# url rewriting slows down proxy a lot

Tags: .htaccess, proxy

i have a proxy script which writes very ugly long URL. the proxy script automaticaly rewrites all href links with long ugly URL,

```
mysite.com/proxy.php?url=somesite.com
mysite.com/proxy.php?url=somesite.com/somedir
mysite.com/proxy.php?url=somesite.com/somedir/somepage.php
```

to fix this i have done 2 things

1. ***edit the proxy script so that all***
   href links are rewritten as

   ```
   mysite.com/somesite.com
   ```
2. ***added a rewrite rule in .htaccess so that short***
   URLs now rewrite...

   mysite.com/somesite.com

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

the problem is that, whenever i click a link on a proxy loaded page, it seems to take a lot longer than before i did all this cosmetic work. is something wrong with my rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test you've written does two file tests (*if 'not-file' and 'not-dir'*) and if they are true, it will execute your `RewriteRule`. This test is done for ***every*** request. Even if the result would've otherwise only required a `HTTP 304` (not modified) response or when the actual files are currently held in memory by Apache.

It's possible that this slows down your site significantly if it contains many (server/client cached) images or other resources. To prevent this, try to filter without the need to access your file system. Filter as much as possible by using a regular expression. The easiest way to do this is by changing the URI path part to something unique, for instance `example.com/u=somesite.com` or even `example.com/p/somesite.com` (p for proxy)).

Your tests will be much faster if all you need to do is a regular expression pattern match as opposed to two file-existence tests (example for `example.com/p/somesite/etc/....`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/p/
RewriteRule ....
```

**Update:** expanded a bit and added small example

*PS: even if you do not want to change your current brief URI scheme, you can use this pattern temporarily to test whether it changes performance for the better.*